# when I have a variables Start=08:22:39 and end=08:23:22. how do I get the difference for these two variables

Tags: command-line

start=08:20:12
end=08:22:12

how to calculate difference.

Kindly help on it..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both hours are at at the same day (and not, for instance, 23:59:00 - 00:01:00), and that the hour is not higher than 23, the following command (in `bash` or POSIX-`sh`) will show you the differences between the two in seconds:

```
$ start="08:20:12" end="08:22:12"
$ echo $(( $(date +"%s" -d "$end") - $(date +"%s" -d "$start") ))
120
```

Another way, without using `date` command, which also checks the the `$end` is bigger than `$start`, and adds 24 hours worth of seconds to `$end` if it isn't:

```
# start="08:20:12" end="08:22:12"

# IFS=: read h m s <<< $start;  START=$(( (3600 * ${h#0} ) + (60 * ${m#0}) + ${s#0} ))
# IFS=: read h m s <<< $end;  END=$(( (3600 * ${h#0} ) + (60 * ${m#0}) + ${s#0} ))
# [[ $END -lt $START ]] && END=$(( $END + (24*60*60) ))

# echo $(( $END - $START ))
120
```

This code also removes the preceding 0 from the hour/minute/second if the number if less than 10 to convert it to a single digit (assumes that all three are double digits).
And write a function that converts the time to seconds.

```
# function convert_to_seconds { IFS=: read h m s <<< $1;  echo $(( (3600 * ${h#0} ) + (60 * ${m#0}) + ${s#0} )) ; }

# START=$(convert_to_seconds "23:59:12")
# END=$(convert_to_seconds "00:01:12")
# [[ $END -lt $START ]] && END=$(( $END + (24*60*60) ))

# echo $(( $END - $START ))
120
```

Comment: The exports are not needed, and only pollute the namespace. I would think using shell arithmetic would be faster than running two external processes. This would be significant if this was used e.g. to determine the period between consecutive events within a large logfile. It would be simple to correct for day roll-over by adding 86400.